# itunes my app was rejected, kids category

Tags: app-store

I try to submit my app, but I still get this message from itunes team:

```
We encourage you to review your app concept and incorporate different content and features or resubmit your app without the Kids category designation.
```

But I have no check box "app for Kids" on app restriction page. How to fix this issue and submit app?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find any solution for this? Please let me know. Thanks!!

Comment: @Jzapata Yes. I just contact with support team and they approve app.

Answer (score 0):

This same went for me !!
I resolved it by managing my Age restriction section.

Head to General > App Information > Age rating
. provide the exact details of your application what is meant to be.
. Do not give a check to made for kids.
. Mention the app for Age 17+ after the Next clicked.[image]